# How to change 'Timestamp'-column language in MySql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, datetime

I have a column which is a Timestamp.

It records something like: `2010-02-08 12:10:22`

Then I use this in php:

```
 $postdate = date( "j F", strtotime( $row['modify_date'] ) );
```

And it can output something like: `8 February`

My Q is, how can I change the date-text so it outputs the month name in another language (swedish specifically)?

Ex: January is in Swedish Januari

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native PHP function for that is [**strftime()**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

> **%B** Full month name, based on the locale   January through December

if the server is not in the swedish locale, use [**setlocale()**](http://www.php.net/setlocale).

That said, I have had so many troubles with `setlocale()` in the past, especially on shared hosting, that I tend to keep an array of month names in whatever config file / dictionary file the project has:

```
$monthnames["de"] = array("Januar", "Februar", "März", "...");
$monthnames["fi"] = array("Tammikuu", "Helmikuu", "...");


echo $monthnames[$language][date("n", strtotime( $row['modify_date'] ))];
```

Comment: How can I set the local time on my virtual server then? Whats the var name?

Comment: What do you mean by local time? The server clock?

Comment: No sorry, I thought by setting the "lc_time_names" to sv_SE it would change all dates to the swedish language. but didn't work :(. I am managing a VPS so I can set whatever variables I like, that's what I meant... hmmmm Maybe I will go with the array then, it's only 12 values anyways.

Comment: If you ask me, go with the array. The correct locale could be anything - `sv_se`, `sv_SE`, `se_SV` (who knows?), `SV`, `sv`, `se_se`? maybe `sv_SE-UTF8`?  I'm exaggerating but there's more than a little truth to it.

Comment: FYI. You left out a quote-mark in the code. Messes up the highlighting :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) then you can output locale-specific names via [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).